# !x is equivalent to (x===undefined || x.length===0)

Tags: angular

In my template I have this (the body of a table):

```
<tbody *ngIf="!matchesInfo && !pendingRequest">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="no-matches">
          <p>There are no matches to create on the selected date</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Where `matchesInfo` is an array, that may be empty or not according to the result of a subscribtion to a service:

```
  this.matchService.getMatchesFromSportradar(this.date).subscribe(result =>{
      this.pendingRequest = false;
      this.matchesInfo = result;
    });
```

The problem is, when I use `<tbody *ngIf="!matchesInfo && !pendingRequest">` nothing gets displayed to the screen, while the message  `There are no matches to create on the selected date` gets displayed when I use `<tbody *ngIf="(matchesInfo===undefined || matchesInfo.length===0) && !pendingRequest">`.

My question is, aren't these two If statements equivalent? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which type and structure of  `this.matchesInfo`? An array of objects?

Comment: @ArtOlshansky yes it's an array of objects.

Comment: So, you can just replace `!matchesInfo` to the `!matchesInfo?.length` _(I guess you got an empty array in result, and `![] === false`)_

Comment: @ArtOlshansky you're right, I should have replace it by `!matchInfo || !matchInfo.length` because we won't have a length if the variable was `undefined`, thus we'll have an error. Can you please post this as a answer to this post so I can accept it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just replace `!matchesInfo` to the `!matchesInfo?.length` *(I guess you got an empty array in `result`, and `![] === false`)*

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you create an empty array simply initiated with `x = []`

```
if (x) alert("x exists");
```

This will fire up the alert, proving that initializing an array is enough for its existence to be true.

So in your case you need to check for its existence and that it is empty.

!x is not equivalent to (x===undefined || x.length===0)

Comment: You're right that's what I ended up doing thanks to the comment of @ArtOlshansky thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `!matchesInfo?.length && !pendingRequest`.

This statement will be true if `matchesInfo` is defined and also have a property `length` witch is `=0`.